# In Redis, is it possible to predicate the inclusion of a member in the result of ZRANGE based on its existence in a different ZSET?

Tags: redis

I'm tracking members in multiple Sorted Sets in Redis as a way to do *multi-column* indexing on the members. As an example, let's say I have two Sorted Sets, `lastseen` (which is epoch time) and `points`, and I store usernames as members in these Sorted Sets.

I'm wanting to use ZREVRANGEBYSCORE against `lastseen` to get a list of users who were recently seen, but I only want a user to be included in the results if its also present in the `points` Sorted Set.

I looked at using ZINTERSTORE to help me do this, but the available AGGREGATE options are not conducive to my scenario. If one of the AGGREGATE options was to use the score from a specific set provided to the ZINTERSTORE command, then it would work, but that's not an option.

---EDIT---

Example:

```
redis> ZADD lastseen 12345 "foo"
redis> ZADD lastseen 12346 "bar"
redis> ZADD lastseen 12347 "sucka"
redis> ZADD points 5 "foo"
redis> ZADD points 9 "bar"
```

Now, if I run:

```
redis> ZREVRANGEBYSCORE lastseen +inf -inf
1) "sucka"
2) "bar"
3) "foo"
```

What I'm looking for is a way to only get `"foo"` and `"bar"` returned by the call to ZREVRANGEBYSCORE for `lastseen` since `"sucka"` isn't resent in the `points` Sorted Set.

I can do:

```
redis> ZINTERSTORE out 2 lastseen points
redis> ZRANGE out 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "foo"
2) "12350"
3) "bar"
4) "12355"
```

As you can see, the ZINTERSTORE does cut out the `"sucka"` member, but the scores for the other two members get aggregated using SUM. There's two other aggregation options (MIN and MAX) available for use with ZINTERSTORE. In this case, using MAX would give me what I'm looking for, but that wouldn't be the case if a user's points were greater than the epoch value for the last time they were seen.

Comment: Multi dimensional indexing in Redis is a topic that's close to my heart. You may want to check out the new [indexing doc page](http://redis.io/topics/indexes) and [redimension library](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/3qjlkk/redimension_ruby_library_implementing/).

Comment: I read through the indexing doc page already -- I need to determine if I can represent my multi-dimensional indexes in a linear way.

Comment: OK, fair enough and apparently I don't understand enough :) could you beef your question with sample data?

Comment: OP has been edited to beef it up with some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you're asking by setting the `WEIGHT` of `points` to 0 and of `lastseen` to 1 when running `ZINTERSTORE` so that only the weight of lastseen is considered:

```
redis> ZINTERSTORE out 2 lastseen points WEIGHTS 1 0
(integer) 2
```

Then, depending on what ordering you're going for, you can either:

```
redis> ZRANGE out 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "foo"
2) "12345"
3) "bar"
4) "12346"
```

or:

```
redis> ZREVRANGE out 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "bar"
2) "12346"
3) "foo"
4) "12345"
```

Comment: AHHHH!!!! Well duh! I'm an idiot for not thinking of setting the weight to zero. Thank you!